# Calling a method when a provider is created

Tags: flutter, state-management, riverpod

With the `ChangeNotifierProvider` widget in Provider, you can call a method, say onInit(), immediately when a provider is created with `create` like so

`ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeChangeNotifier(context: context)..onInit();`

What is the riverpod way of doing the same?

I tried

`final exampleProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose<ExampleChangeNotifier>((ref) => ExampleChangeNotifier(providerRef: ref)..onInit());`

thinking `onInit()` will be called the first time `exampleProvider` is `read` or `watch`ed in the build of a widget but it doesn't get called.

Comment: You need to read the provider.